# Strange KeyProperty failure when using flask-appengine-template

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm using the [flask-appengine-template](https://github.com/kamalgill/flask-appengine-template) from kamalgill and am getting a strange problem.

My `models.py` file looks like this:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class DimensionModel(ndb.Model):
    """"""
    value=ndb.FloatProperty(required=True)
    tolerance=ndb.FloatProperty(required=True)

class StackModel(ndb.Model):
    """Example Model"""
    example_name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    example_description = ndb.TextProperty(required=True)
    dimensions=ndb.KeyProperty(kind='DimensionModel')
    added_by = ndb.UserProperty()
    timestamp = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

and my `forms.py` file looks like this:

```
from flaskext import wtf
from flaskext.wtf import validators
from wtforms.ext.appengine.ndb import model_form

from .models import StackModel


# App Engine ndb model form example
ExampleForm = model_form(StackModel, wtf.Form, field_args={
    'example_name': dict(validators=[validators.Required()]),
    'example_description': dict(validators=[validators.Required()]),
})
```

This gives me the error dump shown below. Everything works fine if I just comment out the `dimensions=ndb.KeyProperty(kind='DimensionModel')` line in models.py. I am not sure where to go from here.

```
INFO     2013-06-16 06:02:20,592 sdk_update_checker.py:244] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2013-06-16 06:02:20,886 api_server.py:153] Starting API server at: http://localhost:39407
INFO     2013-06-16 06:02:20,938 dispatcher.py:164] Starting server "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2013-06-16 06:02:20,947 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
ERROR    2013-06-16 06:02:22,888 wsgi.py:219] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/chris/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 196, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/home/chris/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 255, in _LoadHandler
    handler = __import__(path[0])
  File "/home/chris/code/flask-appengine-template_running/src/run.py", line 5, in <module>
    import application
  File "/home/chris/code/flask-appengine-template_running/src/application/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import urls
   File "/home/chris/code/flask-appengine-template_running/src/application/urls.py", line 10, in <module>
    from application import views
  File "/home/chris/code/flask-appengine-template_running/src/application/views.py", line 20, in <module>
    from forms import ExampleForm
  File "/home/chris/code/flask-appengine-template_running/src/application/forms.py", line 21, in <module>
    'example_description': dict(validators=[validators.Required()]),
  File "/home/chris/code/flask-appengine-template_running/src/lib/wtforms/ext/appengine/ndb.py", line 403, in model_form
    field_dict = model_fields(model, only, exclude, field_args, converter)
  File "/home/chris/code/flask-appengine-template_running/src/lib/wtforms/ext/appengine/ndb.py", line 370, in model_fields
    field = converter.convert(model, props[name], field_args.get(name))
  File "/home/chris/code/flask-appengine-template_running/src/lib/wtforms/ext/appengine/ndb.py", line 179, in convert
    return converter(model, prop, kwargs)
  File "/home/chris/code/flask-appengine-template_running/src/lib/wtforms/ext/appengine/ndb.py", line 327, in convert_KeyProperty
    kwargs['reference_class'] = prop._reference_class
AttributeError: 'KeyProperty' object has no attribute '_reference_class'
INFO     2013-06-16 06:02:22,898 server.py:585] default: "GET /_ah/warmup HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: Are you expecting a user to enter a KeyProperty into a WTForm field?  That's what it's trying to do for you.  Maybe you want to exclude that field from the form.

Comment: What I'm not quite sure about is why the WTForms is even looking for the 'dimension' KeyProperty... I don't specify it in forms.py

Answer (score 4):

```
# App Engine ndb model form example
ExampleForm = model_form(
    StackModel, 
    wtf.Form, 
    only=('example_name', 'example_description'),
    field_args={
        'example_name': dict(validators=[validators.Required()]),
        'example_description': dict(validators=[validators.Required()])})
```

Use **"only"** to restrict the fields that are to be used by the Form.

This works !

Comment: When I encounter that "'ModelConverter' object has no attribute fallback_converter", I solved it using 'only' option. Thank you!